# Hows tags work in liferay?

Tags: tags, liferay, liferay-6

I am new to liferay and am a student. I need to develop a portlet in liferay that allows users to pick tags from the tag pool.

The portlet should look like [this wiki-page](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki?p_p_id=36&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-2&p_p_col_count=1&_36_struts_action=%2Fwiki%2Fedit_page&_36_redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.liferay.com%2Fcommunity%2Fwiki%2F-%2Fwiki%2FMain%2FLiferay%2BUI%2BTaglib&p_r_p_185834411_nodeId=1071674&p_r_p_185834411_title=&_36_editTitle=1&_36_parentTitle=UI+Taglib), take a look at the `Categorization` section.

Can anyone suggest how to develop that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liferay is open source. Please download the portal source and have a look into the journal article portlet.

Hint : Please checkout the liferay-ui taglib. There is a tag called `asset-tags-selector`, just have that in your jsp and you will have tag selector in your portlet.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make it in "Liferay style", you have to implement your data object as an asset. See this [Liferay Asset framework tutorial](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/asset-framework). In the section "Entering and displaying tags and categories" there is an example of `<asset-tags-selector>` that Felix suggested.

Otherwise you can try some javascript libraries. Google can help you with this.